# Cocoa touch view/view-controller conventions

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS dev and am working with an existing project. I just have a quick question regarding how views and view-controllers should be conceptualized and what the conventions are for dealing with them.

I noticed that the base `UIViewController` class has a property `view` which references an actual "physical" (for lack of a better word) view, while the controller essentially manages that physical view (and ties it to the model, etc--standard mvc stuff I understand).

This would suggest the view controller takes conceptual precedence in cocoa touch. However, when adding a subview (to a parent physical view? or to a parent view controller?) it accepts a physical view, not a view controller.

Is it expected that I first create the sub view *controller* (which presumably creates its own physical view) and then pass its `view` property to `addSubView`? I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious in the conventional workflow here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views and view controllers aren't in a 1:1 ratio. A view controller manages as many views as it needs to for a given area of functionality - on the iPhone, typically a screen full of content but this definition is shifting slightly.

The view property of a controller is simply the parent view - this can have as many subviews as you need to do the job. The controller coordinates between those views and the data model to deliver the functionality of your app.

You can have child view controllers, which are added to the view controller hierarchy as well as the view hierarchy (the child view controller's view is added as a subview of the parent view controller's view) but you wouldn't do this for every subview.

There was an excellent talk in WWDC 2012 ("The evolution of view controllers", IIRC) which explained this pretty well.

Comment: Thanks! Any resources/references are appreciated. For others, here is a link to the mentioned "Evolution of View Controllers" video on WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: Besides the WWDC video, everything is in the UIViewController class reference, and the view controller programming guide linked within: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html